# How Can i Fetch a Customized Folder Path using GetFolderPath?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
string downloadArea = Environment.GetFolderPath((Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\My Personal Documents\\CVs");
```

I'm trying to get the path ends with .....\My Personal Documents\CVs

My Personal Documents and CVs are folders that reside under MyDocuments.

The above code gives me a compiler error that says:

> The best overloaded method match for 'System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder)'
>   has some invalid arguments
>
> Another error:
>
> Argument '1': cannot convert from
>   'string' to
>   'System.Environment.SpecialFolder'

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the special "My Documents" folder path first, then append your additional directories with [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784047.aspx):

```
string myDocuments = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
string downloadArea = Path.Combine(myDocuments, "My Personal Documents", "CVs");
```